# Outlookの会議依頼における本文

Tags: vba

エクセルのデータを抽出してOutlookの会議依頼を生成するマクロを組んでいます。しかし問題点が二つあり、

1. マクロによって開かせた会議依頼ウインドウ以外に別のOutlookのウインドウ（メールでも会議依頼でも）が開いていると、そちらに目的のデータが書き込まれてしまって大変
2. この辺（[マクロで書式設定した文字列を予定アイテムの本文に書き込む方法](https://outlooklab.wordpress.com/2017/08/12/%E3%83%9E%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%81%A7%E6%9B%B8%E5%BC%8F%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%88%97%E3%82%92%E4%BA%88%E5%AE%9A%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A4%E3%83%86%E3%83%A0%E3%81%AE%E6%9C%AC/)）をみて文字列の書式は変えられるようになったけど、表が作れない。

上のURLはOutlookVBAの話なので、エクセルから呼び出したOutlookのオブジェクトとその中のWordのコンポーネントのつながりをどう記述すればいいのかわからない、というのが1の原因のような気がしています。2に至っては[MSDSのTable オブジェクト (Word)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/word.table)を参照という名のコピペしてみてるんですが、どう書いてもエラーになります・・・

よろしくお願いいたします。

```
Sub MeetingRequest()
    Dim OutlookObj As Outlook.Application
    Dim MailItemObj As Outlook.AppointmentItem

    Set OutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set MailItemObj = OutlookObj.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
    MailItemObj.MeetingStatus = olMeeting

    MailItemObj.Display

    Dim wrdEditor As Object
    Set wrdEditor = ActiveInspector.WordEditor

    With MailItemObj
        .Subject = "会議依頼"
    End With

    With wrdEditor.Application.Selection
    .Font.Size = 11
    .Font.Color = RGB(91, 155, 213)
    .TypeText "Hello all," & vbCrLf
    .TypeText "This is a meeting request!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    .TypeText "The detail is as follows;"
    End With

    MailItemObj.Display
    Set OutlookObj = Nothing
    Set MailItemObj = Nothing
    Set wrdEditor = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Outlookで出来るかどうか分かりませんが、こんな記事とかページがあります。[Using Tables in RTF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8349827/9014308), [Table Definitions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-10/aa140283(v=office.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#table-definitions), [MSFT-RTF.pdf](https://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/Archive_References/[MSFT-RTF].pdf)

Comment: むむむRTF直イジリですか・・・ハードル高そう・・・